# How can I get carousel on page at Umbraco?

Tags: slider, carousel, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I want to create a carousel, firstly I create a nested content then I added it on my homepage but when I called, it's not working.

```
@{
  string carouselId = "mainCarousel";
  IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> carousel = Model.Value<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(carouselId); }
```

I got error like this object reference not set to an instance of an object. I tried many things but I failed to reach on solve. Btw I'm using v8.1.12.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with this code;

```
var page = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("eea1803b-f093-42f6-8483-b27df3323c2d"));      
var carousel = page.Value<IEnumerable<IPublishedElement>>("mainCarousel");
```